Visual studio Project folder default name is always "New Folder1", why?
I am new to Visual Studio and C.
Recently I discovered on the Internet a new way to organize my Projects in
Folders and kind of ignoring the filters.
This made my program folder structure much better.
Now I know where .exe, .obj etc. files reside in my hard disk directories and how to rearrange them.
From what I can recall my problem started after I corrected a Solution or Project file structure.
Since then when I have selected "Show all files" and I am creating a New Folder for my Project, the New Folder default name is "New Folder1" instead of "New Folder".
I do the following:
Project Name Right click on it, Add -> New Folder a new folder is created with the
default name "New Folder1".
See below the screenshots for clearer representation :
Step 1:
Add New Folder
Step 2:
New Folder default name
Why Am I getting this behavior from visual studio 2022?
p.s. I have already googled and researched many answers but I could not find an answer.
Thank you in advance.
Edit:I cannot answer yet but the question is under consideration by microsoft support.Under consideration

I've read you post 3 times in English and translated it to my native language , it's unclear to me, if the default folder name was XYZ thats a temp name, definitely  you'll going to change it. Would you please explain your Goal ?

This is an article about the exact same thing but on Windows 10.link. My goal is to ideally find which registry key of Visual Studio has changed and the default name counter has been set to 1 for all solutions and projects. If I can`t do that maybe I can create a key that changes that value back to "zero" for lack of better wording instead of 1 that it is now.

I have posted the problem to the developer community here as you suggested and currently I am waiting for feedback. Happy to keep you updated when I get a reply.

Thanks for your kind reply, that issue doesn't exist on my VS Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.11.0 Preview 2.0

I tested it and the situation I encountered is the same as yours. This should be the design of the current updated VS. If you really want to use the initial name of New Folder, I suggest you request this feature to DC. There are more VS developers on DC, and they may be able to help you: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest

Some registry value has been altered. I found an article that uses a registry to change the default New Folder name to whatever someone likes.It doesn`t seem that this is by design.The name counter for default names "New Folder1","New Folder2" e.t.c. somehow got modified.I am searching msdn currently.Thank you for your suggestion.

Thank you for your reply. I searched in the registry but didn't find any item that could change this setting. If you can successfully modify the folder naming setting through the registry or if MSDN provides a feasible method, please post the method as an answer so that people who encounter similar problems can handle it conveniently.

Of course I will. I haven`t found a solution yet though.

I have posted the problem to the developer community here as you suggested and currently I am waiting for feedback. Happy to keep you updated when I get a reply.
